# How to Implement $child method in new AngularFire v0.8.0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

A user is logged in to the website and tries to create a post. Whenever a new post is created, this post gets associated with the user who created the post.

Referring to a [thinkster.io Tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase), which uses older API of AngularFire.

When using AngularFire API v0.8.0, this line of code which adds the post breaks:

```
user.$child('posts').$child(postId).$set(postId);
```

The **Post Factory (post.js)** with the method for creating post is:

```
app.factory('Post',
function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');

  var posts = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  var Post = {
    all: posts,
                                       //Starting of create function
    create: function (post) {
      if (User.signedIn()) {
        var user = User.getCurrent();   //Gets the current logged in user
        post.owner = user.username;

        return posts.$add(post).then(function (ref) {
          var postId = ref.name();

          user.$child('posts').$child(postId).$set(postId); 

          //user.$getRecord('posts').$getRecord(postId).$set(postId);             

          return postId;
        });
      }
    },
                                       //End of create function
```

[Changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html) for AngularFire states that

> `$child()` no longer exists. The data already exists in the parent object and creating additional synchronized children is not efficient and discouraged. Use data transformations, flatten your data, or drop down to the Firebase SDK and use its `child()` method.

I am confused as to how to change the code to work with the update in the API.

**After Edit**

This is the getCurrent method:

```
getCurrent: function(){ // retrieves current user
  return $rootScope.currentUser;
},
```

Which belongs to **user.js Factory**:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('User', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, Auth, $rootScope) {
 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');

 var users = $firebase(ref);
 var usersdiv = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

 var User = {

    create: function (authUser, username) {
      users[username] = {
        md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
        username: username
      };
      users.$update(username, {
          md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
          username: username
      }).then(function (dataRef) {
          dataRef.setPriority(authUser.uid);
          setCurrentUser(username);
      });
    }, // end of create method

    findByUsername: function(username){
      if(username){
        return usersdiv.$getRecord(username);
      }
    },

    getCurrent: function(){ // retrieves current user
      return $rootScope.currentUser;
    },

    signedIn: function(){ //checks if user is signed in
      return $rootScope.currentUser !== undefined;
    }

  }; // end of User

  // so that we can pull info about user when logged in
  function setCurrentUser (username){
    $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
  }

  //for logins and refreshes
  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function(e, authUser){

      var queryRef = ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid);

      var queryArray = $firebase(queryRef).$asArray();

      queryArray.$loaded().then(function() {
        setCurrentUser(queryArray.$keyAt(0));
      });
  });

  //logout
  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function(){
    delete $rootScope.currentUser;
  });
  return User;
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should include your User.getCurrent() method and it returns, since that is the key line that is failing for you. People should not have to go read a tutorial in order to help you answer the question here.

Comment: I'm sorry that you had to read through. I had thought that the getCurrent() is working just fine so i did't include it in the question, my mistake. I have added the User Factory. And getCurrent() method for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Answer is:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('Post',
    function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User) {
      var postsref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');
      var usersref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');   
      var posts = $firebase(postsref).$asArray();     

      var Post = {
        all: posts,

        create: function (post) {
          if (User.signedIn()) {
            var user = User.getCurrent();        
            post.owner = user.username;      
            return posts.$add(post).then(function (ref) {
              var postId = ref.name();
              //a child in user forge should be made with its key as postID
              usersref.child(post.owner).child('posts').child(postId).set(postId);
              return postId;
            });
          }
        },

        find: function (postId) {
          return $firebase(postsref.child(postId)).$asObject();
        },

        delete: function (postId) {
          if (User.signedIn()) {
            var postToDel = Post.find(postId);
            postToDel.$loaded().then(function(){
                var p = posts[postToDel.$id];
                posts.$remove(postId).then(function(){
                    $firebase(usersref.child(p.owner).child('posts')).$remove(p.$id);                    
                });
            });
          }
        },
```

**Thus, child can be used at Firebase SDK Level.**

*Example:*

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var userArray = $firebase(ref.child('user')).$asArray();
var userObject = $firebase(ref.child('user')).$asObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a synchronized object locally (what $child used to do) just to set a value in Firebase. You can do this at any time with the Firebase ref you've already created. I can't tell exactly what the data structure of user is since it wasn't included, but something like this:

```
new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child('...path/to/posts').child(postId).set(postId);
```

Most likely, this belongs on your user object, so that in the Post factory, you can just do something like `user.addPost(postId)`.

Comment: I followed your guideline, calling _user.addPost(postId)_ is illegal as user is just a variable. Alternatively if i use `User.addPost(postId)` The FireBase adds a post without any reference to the user who posted it.
The method I made in User Factory is:
`addPost: function(postId){ // adds the post
      var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users').child('posts').child(postId).set(postId);
    }`

Comment: you haven't included the user's id in your URL. You have users/posts/postId.

Comment: do you mean to say that i have to use startAt and endAt combination to narrow down the user results to single record and then update that specific user?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. As Kato suggested, you will have to use the child function in the Firebase object. I chose to add the post to the user in the Post factory itself.

#### Adding Post to User

```
var usersref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
usersref.child(post.owner).child('posts').child(postId).set(postId);
```

The Entire **post.js** is as below:

```js
'use strict';

app.factory('Post', 
    function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, User){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');
        var usersref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
        var posts = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

        var Post = {
            all : posts,

            create : function(post){
                if(User.signedIn()){
                    var user = User.getCurrent();
                    post.owner = user.username;
                    return posts.$add(post).then(function(ref){
                        var postId = ref.name();
                        usersref.child(post.owner).child('posts').child(postId).set(postId);
                        return postId;
                    });

                }
            },

            find: function(postId){
                return $firebase(ref.child(postId)).$asObject();
            },

            delete: function(postId){
                if(User.signedIn()){
                    var postToDel = Post.find(postId);
                    postToDel.$loaded().then(function(){
                        var p = posts[postToDel.$id];
                        posts.$remove(postId).then(function(){
                            $firebase(usersref.child(p.owner).child('posts')).$asArray().$remove(p.$id);
                        });

                    });
                }
            }
        };

        return Post;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Vikas and @kato 
The code is perfect and i too was looking to add the child from my post factory. I am a beginner at web development and learning each day. Thank you both of you. :)

Comment: I think `$firebase(usersref.child(p.owner).child('posts')).$asArray().$remove(p.$id);` in your delete function is not working. Please check.

Comment: Just Figured the correct way. Deleting $asArray() from above line of code works well. Though i'm not sure why the above line fails. Thus the **correct code is:**
`$firebase(usersref.child(p.owner).child('posts')).$remove(p.$id);`